# Parse inbox for non delivery receipts using c# (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, email

Anyone know of a c# library for parsing non delivery receipts in an inbox (and one that categorizes by which type of failure / bounce).

Comment: What kind of Inbox? Thunderbird or GMail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling bounced mails is not a trivial task. There are different bounce types (hard/soft bounces) and the message content will differ, depending on the smtp server sending the message back to your inbox.

I ended up rolling a *learning* bouncemail processor on my own. It basically gets the messages from the inbox and applies a big load of regualar expressions a la

```
(?:alias|account|recipient|address|email|mailbox|user).*full
```

to it. If no rule matches, it gets forwarded for manual handling and a new rule for that kind of message is added to the processor.

If you have the budget, BounceInspector is one of the commercial products for that kind of job.

Comment: Good start.  And a good idea.  Sounds similar to a rules engine for URL parsing i worked on...  Thanks!